# Magento - Cart update quantity on single product

Tags: magento

In my cart, there is the "Update Quantity" button below that updates all product quantities. I'd like to move this under each product row and make it so that it only updates that products quantity. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently single form works for all the items in cart.
You will have to make one form for each item.
Rest will work as expected.